# How to solve eclipse(Mars) prompt blank error dialog when compare two commits in git history

Tags: eclipse, egit

In one git project's 'History view', select two commits, right click and check 'Compare with Each Other'.
Diff tree not shown but an empty error dialog.

Eclipse Luna version is fine. I checked .log file in workspace, but nothing usable message found.

eclipse-jee-mars-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64, OSX 10.10.4, jdk1.8.0_51

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to update your egit extension to version 4.0.1.

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.egit/releases/4.0.1

This release fixes the following bugs:

- **Bug 467714: Blank history view in Java perspective with EGit**
- Bug 470012: NPE in BranchSelectionDialog.checkPage(BranchSelectionDialog.java:205)
- Bug 470640: NPE in CommitMessageComponent.getHeadCommitInfo

You can check for the update via `Help->Check for Updates`.

Comment: <img title="Blank Dialog" src="http://aaba.me/tmp/egit-blank-prompt.png" /> <img title="EGit version" src="http://aaba.me/tmp/egit-version.png" /> Seems this bugfix not include my conditions.

Comment: A very similar bug still occurs with egit 4.0.3, on linux. The content pane seems to not be packed (smaller than the dialog size).